# What is going wrong during web2py form validation?

Tags: forms, web2py

I have a fairly simple web2py form with a few validators like, IS_FLOAT_IN_RANGE(...) on its fields. When I try to submit the form when it has fields which don't pass validation the form will fail the first validation, but will not report there were any errors. If I then resubmit the same form, validation will fail once again.

Worse, if I submit valid information, it will not submit unless I submit the same form twice. The view is simply `{{=form}}`

The controller looks like this:

```
@auth.requires_login()
def addpipelines():
    form = FORM(INPUT(_name="type", _value="insert", _type="hidden"),
            INPUT(_name="project", _value="Project", requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
            INPUT(_name="value", _value="Value", requires=IS_FLOAT_IN_RANGE(-1e100, 1e100)),
            BR(), BR(),
            INPUT(_type="submit", _value="Add"),
           _method="POST")

    if request.post_vars.type == "insert" and form.process().accepted:
       request.post_vars["blub"] = "blargh"

    return dict(form=form)
```

```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if request.post_vars.type == "insert" and form.process().accepted:
```

Note, in Python, the part of the above expression after the `and` will not be evaluated when the part before the `and` is false, so `form.process()` will only get called when the form is submitted. However, for form processing to work properly, `form.process()` must also be called when the form is first created (because it adds a hidden _formkey field and checks its value with a copy of the formkey placed in the session in order to protect against CSRF attacks and double submission). Instead, try switching the order of the conditions:

```
if form.process().accepted and request.post_vars.type == "insert":
```